# PHP Extract Specific Character from string

Tags: php, regex

i have the bellow string

```
$LINE = TCNU1573105  HDPE HTA108  155   155  000893520918 PAL990  25.2750 MT  28.9750 MT
```

and i want extract the `PAL990` from the above string. actually extract PAL990 string or any string that has PAL followed by some digits Like PAL222 or PAL123

i tried many ways and could not get the result. i used,

```
substr ( $LINE, 77, 3)
```

but when the value in different position i get the wrong value.

Comment: How can you describe the context where the `PAL990` is? How do you think a regex engine can find that substring? Look, `HTA108` looks identical in terms of the chars your expected match consists of, so you may only rely on the context.

Comment: What's the format of the string? and give more samples

Comment: if there any specific pattern you need to look for, give more example

Comment: Do you want to extract PAL990 string only or any string that has PAL followed by some digits? Like PAL222 or PAL123 are supposed to be captured or not? If you just need PAL990 then you don't need regex

Comment: this is the format @RAN_0915 TCNU1573105 HDPE HTA108 155 155 000893520918 PAL990 25.2750 MT 28.9750 MT

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi yes let me correct it, any string that has PAL and followed by any digit. so it could be PAL990 or PAL123 digit do not matter. as long as PAL is there in the string.

Comment: This information should be added to the question itself.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$LINE = "TCNU1573105  HDPE HTA108  155   155  000893520918 PAL990  25.2750 MT  28.9750 MT";
if (preg_match('~\bPAL\d+\b~', $LINE, $res)) {
    echo $res[0]; // => PAL990
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Qtv0L0) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3PC1Tu/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `PAL` - a `PAL` substring
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

The [`preg_match` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will return the first match.

Note that in case your string contains similar strings in between hyphens/whitespace you will no longer be able to rely on word boundaries, use custom whitespace boundaries then, i.e.:

```
'~(?<!\S)PAL\d+(?!\S)~'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3PC1Tu/1)

**EDIT**

If you may have an optional whitespace between `PAL` and digits, you may use

```
preg_replace('~.*\b(PAL)\s?(\d+)\b.*~s', '$1$2', $LINE)
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/J33D5w) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3PC1Tu/3).

Or, match the string you need with spaces, and then remove them:

```
if (preg_match('~\bPAL ?\d+\b~', $LINE, $res)) {
    echo str_replace(" ", "", $res[0]);
}
```

See yet [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/3ozypl)

Note that `?` makes the preceding pattern optional (1 or 0 occurrences are matched).

Comment: This worked but what is there is white space between PAL and 990 like this ""PAL 
  990" and still want the output to be PAL990

Comment: what i mean is sometimes it could contain white space or sometimes it may not contain any white space. in that case how would regex could handle?

Comment: Yes, sure. The `?` makes a pattern optional.

Comment: Yes Your Right. best answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "123ABC1234 *$%^&abc.";
$newstr = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\']/','',$string);
echo $newstr;
```

**Output:ABCabc**

Comment: What question are you answering?